# Array alias for function Node js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, alias

I am trying to use a variable as an alias for an array, the idea is that the variable works as an alias to achieve inserting the data according to the parameter that is passed to the function.

```
    const _ = require('underscore');
    var ha = [];
    var cha = [];
    // livedata insert all data (true or false) into array cha
    // if data contains true valor then insert data in array ha
    HA("cha",open,high,low,close);

    function HA(mode,o,h,l,c){
        var open = Number(o);
        var high = Number(h);
        var low = Number(l);
        var close = Number(c);

        if (mode == "ha" ){
            var arr = ha;         // <-- variable as array alias
        }else{
            var arr = cha;        // <-- variable as array alias
        };

        if (arr == ""){
        arr.push({open,high,low,close});    
        }else{
        console.log("ARRAY");
        console.log(_.last(arr).open);
        console.log(Number(_.last(arr).open));
        console.log("ARRAY");        
        var lhao = Number(_.last(arr).open); 
        var lhac = Number(_.last(arr).close);   

        var hao = ((lhao + lhac) / 2 ).toFixed(8);
        var hac = ((open + high + low + close) / 4).toFixed(8);
        var hah = Math.max(hao, high, hac);
        var hal = Math.min(hao, low, hac);

        var open = hao;
        var high = hah;
        var low = hal;
        var close = hac;

        arr.push({open,high,low,close});        
        console.log(arr);
        };      
    };
```

I have researched but I have not achieved the objective.

Can you help me in the search for the solution, some method or library with which I can use the variable as an alias?

Language: Node Js

Comment: Looking through your code, I can't figure out what this is even supposed to do.  You really do need to post a fully runnable example and explain what is the expected behavior and the desired behavior.  I did pull this down and make some tweaks -- the variable `arr` *is* indeed being set correctly.  However, since you don't declare `arr` with the `var` keyword, it is a global variable and is overwritten on the second run.

Comment: I was missing a parameter in my original code and I got Nan's error. I have also declared the var arr.
Very Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an object and store two arrays within that object, one for the 'ha' results and one for the 'cha' results. Here is an example of how to do this and how to access the correct array, depending on the mode:

```
results = { ha: [], cha: [] };

function HA(mode, value) {
  results[mode].push(value);
}

HA('ha', 1);
HA('ha', 4);
HA('ha', 9);

HA('cha', 111);
HA('cha', 333);
HA('cha', 999);

// The ha results: [ 1, 4, 9 ]
console.log('The ha results:', results['ha']);
// The cha results: [ 111, 333, 999 ]
console.log('The cha results:', results['cha']);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the `arr` variable to be restricted to each function call you need to make the `arr`variable local to the function like below

```
//....

function HA(mode,o,h,l,c){
   //....
   var arr;

   if (mode == "ha" ){
      arr = ha;         // <-- variable as array alias
   }else{
      arr = cha;        // <-- variable as array alias
   };

   //.....
```